# Flutte - JSON deserialized data fetched to FutureBuilder return null value

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, null, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to return ListView of photos via FutureBuilder fetched with data from API. While values are added to List in my service and assigned properly, values fetched to List Builder are null. I don't know why calling service method to return Future<List> returns list of null.

My model:

```
class Photo {
  String id;
  String photoDesc;
  String photoAuthor;
  String photoUrlSmall;
  String photoUrlFull;
  String downloadUrl;
  int likes;

  Photo(
      {this.id,
      this.photoDesc,
      this.photoAuthor,
      this.photoUrlSmall,
      this.photoUrlFull,
      this.downloadUrl,
      this.likes});

  Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    photoDesc = json['description'] != null
        ? json['description']
        : json['alt_description'];
    photoAuthor = json['user']['name'] != null
        ? json['user']['name']
        : json['user']['username'];
    photoUrlSmall = json['urls']['small'];
    photoUrlFull = json['urls']['full'];
    downloadUrl = json['links']['download'];
    likes = json['likes'];
  }
}
```

My service:

```
Future<List<Photo>> getRandomData1() async {
    List<Photo> randomPhotos;
    _response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        '$unsplashUrl/photos/random/?client_id=${_key.accessKey}&count=30'));
    if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
      return randomPhotos = (json.decode(_response.body) as List).map((i) {
        Photo.fromJson(i); 
        print(Photo.fromJson(i).id); // **i.e. printing returns proper values**
          }).toList();
        } else {
          print(_response.statusCode);
          throw 'Problem with the get request';
        }
      }
```

My builder:

```
class RandomPhotosListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomPhotosListViewState createState() => _RandomPhotosListViewState();
}

class _RandomPhotosListViewState extends State<RandomPhotosListView> {
  final UnsplashApiClient unsplashApiClient = UnsplashApiClient();
  Future _data;

  ListView _randomPhotosListView(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("${data[index]}"); 
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = unsplashApiClient.getRandomData1();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _data,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);          // i.e. snapshot.data here is list of nulls
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text("error: ${snapshot.error}");
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return _randomPhotosListView(snapshot.data);
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, your map function is not returning the parsed object, which could be the problem. Try `return Photo.fromJson(i)` or `.map(i => Photo.fromJson(i)).toList()`

Comment: you need check your connectionState if it is equal to ConnectionState.done and after that check snapshot.hasData or snapshot.error

Comment: Thank you @daddygames! Such small thing but I wasted 3h trying to solve it :D

Comment: @sdobrzan It happens to all of us. That's one of the great aspects of SO. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as such. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this issue is because you need to return the parsed object in your mapping function.

**Solution #1 - add the `return` keyword to your existing code**

```
return randomPhotos = (json.decode(_response.body) as List).map((i) {
 return Photo.fromJson(i); // <-- added return keyword here
}).toList();
```

**Solution #2 - Use Arrow to define the return**

This solution suits your code since you aren't manipulating the Photo object or any other data within the mapping.

```
return randomPhotos = (json.decode(_response.body) as List).map((i) => Photo.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Either solution should work. Choose what suits your coding style and your needs.